# I want start my search in datalist after entering 3 character?

Tags: javascript, angular, datalist

this is my html code i want start searching values after entering 3 charater :-

```
<input id="restaurants" list="lstRestaurants" type="text" class="form-control form-input input-search input-section clearable" placeholder="Name of Restaurant" [(ngModel)]="searchModel.restaurant" name="restaurant" #restaurant="ngModel">
<datalist id="lstRestaurants">
   <option *ngFor="let restaurant of allRestaurants" value="{{restaurant.name}}"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Could you add your js code for search as well and explain what your problem is?

Answer (score 0):

you should set watch on `searchModel.restaurant` :

```
$scope.$watch('searchModel.restaurant', function(newValue){
 if(newValue.length === 3){
   //search on your datalist
   alert("Search by newValue");
 }});
```

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this should get you nearer your answer.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#restaurants', function() {
var myLength = $("#restaurants").val().length;
if (myLength > 2) {
      alert("Do search now")
    };
alert("each letter you type this pops up");
});
```

Comment: Dude its not working its giving  alert every time i typed a character but when i am removing alert then its searching on enter of first character